# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'dialog'

Tags: jquery, jsf

Below is my JSF code and corresponding HTML code which its gets converted into,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static-files/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static-files/js/functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static-files/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static-files/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<ui:composition>
<div id="myForm" style="visibility:hidden">
<a4j:commandLink id="cmdLinkClose" value="No Thanks"></a4j:commandLink>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */

$("a[id$='cmdLinkClose']").click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('close');
});

/* ]]> */ 
</script>

</ui:composition>
```

**HTML code :**

```
<a href="#" id="j_id3:cmdLinkClose" name="j_id3:cmdLinkClose" 
onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('j_id3',event,{'similarityGroupingId':'j_id3:cmdLinkClose'
,'parameters':{'j_id3:cmdLinkClose':'j_id3:cmdLinkClose'} } );return false;">No Thanks</a>
```

When I click on 'No Thanks' link, am getting below exception in Java Script console.

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'dialog'`

And I also have below code in my xhtml page,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
   var $h=jQuery.noConflict();          
   function myFunction() 
   {

        $h(document).ready(function() {
            $h("#myForm").attr("style", "display:block");
            $h("#myForm").dialog({
                open: function(event, ui) {
                    jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close").html('<span>Close</span>');
                },
                duration: 800,
                height: 300,
                minWidth: 300,
                width: 300,
                position: [490, 160],
                zIndex: 99999999,
                modal: true,
                show: {
                    effect: 'puff',
                    duration: 400
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: 'puff',
                    duration: 400
                }

            });
        });
   }

   myFunction();

    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

After googling I learnt that it could be because of not importing relevant Jquery Java Script files. But, in my case am not sure which Java Script I need to import/remove.

**UPDATE:**

I replaced `jquery-ui.min.js` with `jquery-1.9.1.min.js`. Below is the error am getting now,

[image]

Comment: Since you accepted an answer, may I assume that your problem is finally solved? I do not see the right answer anywhere though... RichFaces namely also bundles jQuery, thus there is aboslutely no need to manually download include jQuery then. Note that RichFaces has also already a dialog component, so there's technically no need to fiddle with jQuery UI either.

Comment: I need not had to include `jquery-latest.js`. That was creating some conflict with other includes. My problem statement is resolved. But, am facing some other problems now. Will try and if I cannot troubleshoot, I ll raise a new question. And I didn't get why you are specific about RichFaces Jquery!

Comment: Kindly let us know if you have a better solution to the actual problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like you've included three times jQuery library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static-files/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static-files/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

You just need to include once and place it before jQuery UI and your other jQuery file

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static-files/js/functions.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static-files/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: After I did these changes, now am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined" from `jquery-ui.min.js`

Comment: @VikasV get the latest jQuery UI, maybe incompatible issue.

Comment: I replaced `jquery-ui.min.js` with `jquery-1.9.1.min.js`. Now am getting a different error. I have updated my question with this new error and also with the screen shot.