# JQuery popup.....Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'

Tags: php, javascript

I have been searching for the solution to this problem for a few days now and have gained a few grey hairs in the process. I am echoing a JQuery popup script in php:

```
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>            
  <script src="functions.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { JQueryAlert("INSERT MESSAGE HERE!", 120); }); </script>';
```

The problem is, sometimes it fires and sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't fire it outputs the following error message in Chromes JS console: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'

From what I can discern from similar questions([Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'dialog'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963209/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-has-no-method-dialog)), the problem is a duplicate call of a javascript library, however, I have eliminated this possibility by whittling my javascript libraries to a bare minimum(any less and it won't be able to function). Any idea what is causing this?? I would be eternally grateful to anyone who can provide a solution!!

Comment: I have searched a little and found a similar error caused by a the jquery-UI library attempting to use the 'dialog' method before it has actually loaded. Are you loading the libraries before any other script?

Comment: Hi frrlod, thx for the reply. Yes, as far as I can tell, I am loading the libraries before any other script.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't a fix, but since I can't see the rest of your code, here is a potential workaround, where you basically check if the dialog function exists, if so, we create the alert, if not, we wait 100 milliseconds, and try again:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     function jqalert(msg) {
       if (typeof($.fn.dialog) != 'undefined') 
         JQueryAlert(msg, 120); 
       else 
         setTimeout(function() { jqalert(msg); }, 100);
     }
     jqalert("INSERT MESSAGE HERE!");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Might have to use this if I can't find a fix.